# Vector out of range c++ initialization

Tags: c++, vector

Been trying to find out why I can't seem to get 2d vectors to work properly. Tried this and it only works if I initiliaze the vector of vectors as a local variable. Otherwise I get an out of range error.

```
vector <string> allSymbols;

std::vector<std::vector<bool>> wholeMap(allSymbols.size(), std::vector<bool>(allTerms.size() + 2));

void fillWholeMap()
{


    cout << allSymbols.size() << endl;
    cout << allTerms.size() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < allSymbols.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < allTerms.size() + 2; j++)
        {
            wholeMap[i][j]=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you expect your second line of code to accomplish.  Maybe you can describe your higher-level goal.  Do you want a 2D-matrix of boolean flags?  Maybe use an existing matrix class or roll your own simple one with a clean interface.

Comment: Please a whole [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you do initialise `wholeMap` **after** you have filled `allSymbols` and `allTerms`. Alternative is to initialise `wholeMap` with a 0 size and to use `vector::push_back()` method to dynamically add.

Comment: Sorry, Yes I am trying to create a 2d vector that is all boolean flags. I am having trouble initializing the 2d vector. I do initialize the other two first and I have tried vector::push_back()  My second line of code is my attempt to create a vector of vector with bools inside. This vector of vectors is supposed to have the size I defined. However, I am finding it is not reserving any space.

Comment: The power of C++ is utilized best if you use appropriate data structures that encapsulate the complicated stuff so you can solve one small problem at a time.  You can get some inspirations for writing a simple matrix class from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/1392132).  Otherwise, you could use an external library.  In addition, I recommend you stay away from `std::vector<bool>` and use `std::vector<char>` instead unless you know exactly what you are doing.  It will save you a lot of bad surprises;  `std::vector<bool>` is the enfant terrible of the STL.

Answer (score 0):

A global variable is initialised even before `main()` is called. Your `wholeMap` is being initialised with size 0 when you create it as a global variable. This is because the size of `allSymbols` is 0 at that time.